# Проблема общения сервера (java) с клиентом (c#)

Tags: java, c#

Есть сервер на Java и клиент на C#. Сервер ловит запросы на подключение клиента с помощью ServerSocket, затем для каждого нового клиента создаёт новый поток с его личным сокетом. Клиент подключается к серверу посредством TCPClient.

Потоки ввода/вывода сокета на сервере сконвертированы в **DataInputStream** и **DataOutputStream** для удобства, на клиента это **NetworkStream**.

[Исходники сервера, которые могут быть полезны](http://pastebin.com/UDhGFHsQ)

[Исходники клиента, которые могут быть полезны](http://pastebin.com/sFBTBit2)

Собственно **проблема**: если авторизацию клиента трассировать на клиенте и сделать паузу перед считыванием кода результата, то всё хорошо. Если запускать без точек останова, то клиент не может считать из потока целое число - код результата и зависает в его ожидании, хотя он сервером отправляется корректно.

Подскажите, куда деваются данные из потока? Может, я неправильно использую flush? Как реализовать этот обмен правильно?

Comment: Магия... Попробуйте взять Wireshark и посмотреть что именно происходит.

Comment: небольшое замечание: на стороне java в `readString` поменяйте `read` на `readFully`, `read` не гарантирует, что по завершении будет заполнен весь буфер. при создании строки из массива, явно указывайте кодировку в конструкторе, по-умолчанию она там системная.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Я покопался и установил проблему. Всё-таки целое число считывалось, но не целиком, а только первый байт. Как я понял, это случалось потому, что сервер пишет данные побайтно, а клиент при первом же обнаружении данных начинает их считывать. Сейчас пытаюсь решить уже эту проблему.